# Monadic IO with ramda and ramda-fantasy

Tags: node.js, functional-programming, ramda.js, ramda-fantasy

Trying to figure out how the IO monad works.

Using the code below I read `filenames.txt` and use the results to rename files in the directory `testfiles`. This is obviously unfinished, so instead of actually renaming anything I log to console. :)

My questions are:

1. I call `runIO` twice, but it feels like it only should be called
   once, in the end?
2. I'm want to use `renameIO` instead of `renaneDirect` but can't
   find the proper syntax.

Any other suggestions are also appreciated, I'm new to FP!

```
    var R = require('ramda');
    var IO = require('ramda-fantasy').IO
    var fs = require('fs');

    const safeReadDirSync = dir => IO(() => fs.readdirSync(dir));
    const safeReadFileSync = file => IO(() => fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8'));

    const renameIO = (file, name) => IO(() => console.log('Renaming file ' + file + ' to ' + name + '\n'));
    const renameDirect = (file, name) => console.log('Renaming file ' + file + ' to ' + name + '\n');

    safeReadFileSync("filenames.txt") // read future file names from text file
            .map(R.split('\n')) // split into array
            .map(R.zip(safeReadDirSync('./testfiles/').runIO())) // zip with current file names from dir
            .map(R.map(R.apply(renameDirect))) // rename
            .runIO(); // go!
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not too far off a solution.

Too avoid the second call to `runIO` you can make use of the fact that the `IO` type in Ramda Fantasy implements the [`Apply`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply) interface from the fantasyland spec. This allows you to lift a function (like your `renameDirect`) to accept arguments of the `IO` type and apply the function to the values contained within the `IO` instances.

We can make use of [`R.ap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) here, which has a signature (specialised here to `IO`) of `IO (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO -> b`. This signature suggests that if we have an `IO` instance that contains a function that takes some type `a` and returns some type `b`, along with another `IO` instance that contains some type `a`, we can produce an `IO` instance containing some type of `b`.

Before we get into that, we can make a slight change to your use of `R.zip` then `R.apply(renameDirect)` by combining the two using [`R.zipWith(renameDirect)`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap).

Now your example can now look like:

```
var R = require('ramda')
var IO = require('ramda-fantasy').IO
var fs = require('fs')

const safeReadDirSync = dir => IO(() => fs.readdirSync(dir));
const safeReadFileSync = file => IO(() => fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8'))
const renameDirect = (file, name) => console.log('Renaming file ' + file + ' to ' + name + '\n')

const filesIO = R.map(R.split('\n'), safeReadFileSync('filenames.txt'))
const testfilesDirIO = safeReadDirSync('./testfiles/')

const renameDirectIO = (files, names) =>
  R.ap(R.map(R.zipWith(renameDirect), files), names)

renameDirectIO(testfilesDirIO, filesIO).runIO()
```

In this example we've created an instance of `IO (a -> b)` here by calling `R.map(R.zipWith(renameDirect), files)` which will partially apply `R.zipWith(renameDirect)` with the value stored in `files`. This is then given to `R.ap` along with the `names` value, which will produce a new `IO` instance containing the effective result of something equivalent to `IO(() => R.zipWith(renameDirect, value.runIO(), names.runIO())`

Now because having to call `R.map` to partially apply against the first argument to `R.ap` tends to be a bit clunky, there is another helper function [`R.lift`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) that can be useful for this purpose, which takes care of the job of lifting a given function to produce a new function that now accepts `Apply` instances.

So in the above example:

```
const renameDirectIO = (files, names) =>
  R.ap(R.map(R.zipWith(renameDirect), files), names)
```

Can be simplified to:

```
const renameDirectIO = R.lift(R.zipWith(renameDirect))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, even I am new to FP. Have been using ramda for a long time now. But using Applicative Functors, and lifting, still remain confusing. This answer will help me grasp these concepts better.